# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=LoginInfo;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MJ;Password=12345");
    con.Open();

    if (tbRegisterConfirmPassword.Text != string.Empty || tbRegisterPassword.Text != string.Empty || tbRegisterUser.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;
           
        if (tbRegisterPassword.Text == tbRegisterConfirmPassword.Text)
        {
            command = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_acc where username = '" + tbRegisterUser + "'", con);
            dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                dr.Close();
                lbRegister.Text = "Username Already Taken";
                lbRegister.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                dr.Close();

                command = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_acc values (@username, @password)", con);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", tbRegisterUser.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", tbRegisterPassword.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Your account has now been registered", "Registration Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lbRegister.Text = "Password does not match";
            lbRegister.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        lbRegister.Text = "Please fill out all the fields";
        lbRegister.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: And never do select *

Comment: And never store an end user password in cleartext.

Comment: And always include a column list in your `INSERT` clause.

Comment: Oh and [`AddWithValue` is evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: The error message says it all. You're trying to insert a record into a table which would duplicate the primary key. And all that other stuff everyone said about SQL injection and not storing passwords in clear text.

Comment: One more thing... don't forget to [close or dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448335/dispose-the-connection-or-close-the-connection) your database connections.

Comment: Using entity framework would reduce this code to about 10 lines, mostly setting labels to error messages, and it would fix all those other things people pointed out in the comments (apart from the "do not store passwords in clear text" one)

Comment: `if (tbRegisterConfirmPassword.Text != string.Empty || tbRegisterPassword.Text != string.Empty || tbRegisterUser.Text != string.Empty)` - i suspect these should be `&&`'ed

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it might look with EF:

```
private void SetRegLabel(string s){
    lbRegister.ForeColor = s == null ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
    lbRegister.Text = s;
}

private void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetRegLabel(null);

    if(tbRegisterConfirmPassword.Text != tbRegisterPassword.Text)
      SetRegLabel("Passwords don't match");

    else if (new[] {tbRegisterConfirmPassword, tbRegisterPassword, tbRegisterUser}.Any(tb => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))) {
      SetRegLabel("Fill in all fields");

    else if(context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == tbRegisterUser.Text)) {
      SetRegLabel("Username taken");

    else {
      context.Users.Add(new User(){ 
        UserName = tbRegisterUser.Text, 
        Password = Convert.ToBase64String(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("saaalt33"+tbRegisterPassword.Text)))
      });
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
```